# How can I drag marker without long pressing it in Google Maps in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-maps-markers, draggable

In Google Maps, we can drag markers by long pressing it. It is a built-in feature of Google Maps. However, I need to drag markers without long pressing it. Is it possible? If so, how?